# Hierarchy Datagrid Display in Wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, hierarchy

hi am new to wpf can any body help me how to display hierarchy /grouping in wpf datagrid  using backend as sqlserver 2005 ,language c#.

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

I've used infragistics xamDataGrid Express (which is free to use) and I believe it supports hierarchical data display.  You can give that a try:

http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx#Downloads